# SQL Update Tuples with choices

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-workbench

```
update review set content = "Perfect place to eat" or "WOW" WHERE rating = 5.0;
```

How do I use or to set something randomly among the choices?

This is the error:

> 1292 Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'Perfect place to eat'
> 1292 Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'WOW'

Comment: Regarding the source of the error message: `OR` is an logical operator and MySQL tries to convert both `"Perfect place to eat"` and `"WOW"` to  a boolean value. Of course this is not possible, but the query doesn't fail, similar to `cast('WOW' as INTEGER)` which simply returns 0 (instead of failing the query like most (all?) DBMSes besides MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rand()`:

```
update review
    set content = (case when rand() < 0.5 then 'Perfect place to eat'
                        else 'WOW'
                   end)
    where rating = 5.0;
```

If you have multiple strings, you could do:

```
update review
    set content = (case floor(rand() * 3)
                      when 0 then 'string1'
                      when 1 then 'string2'
                      when 2 then 'string3'
                   end)
    where rating = 5.0;
```

Comment: So if I have more than one string statements would I do: update review
    set content = (case when rand() < 0.5 then 'Perfect place to eat' case when rand() < 0.5 then 'Amazing'
                        else 'WOW'
                   end)
    where rating = 5.0;